# Google Play Store says compatible (with my app) devices decreased

Tags: android, gps

Hello I added GPS functions to my application. When I tried to upload new version to play store, it says me compatible device was 7200, but now this number decreased to 6446. Is this because of the android devices which does not have gps hardware?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this because of the android devices which does not have gps hardware?

Yes. The additional permissions implicitly result in feature requirements for network/GPS location as described in [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions).